# C++ : Garage Sale Algorithm

Tags: c++, algorithm

I'm studying Dasgupta's "Algorithms". I solved this problem in C++:

> The garage sale problem. On a
> given Sunday morning, there are \$n\$ garage sales going on, \$g_{1}, \cdots, g_{n}\$.
> For each garage sale \$g_{j}\$ , you have an estimate of its value to
> you, \$v_{j}\$ . For any two garage sales you have an estimate of the
> transportation cost \$d_{ij}\$ of getting from \$g_{i}\$ to \$g_{j}\$ . You are also given
> the costs \$d_{0j}\$ and \$d_{j0}\$ of going between your home and each garage sale.
> You want to find **a tour of a subset of the given garage sales,
> starting and ending at home, that maximizes your total benefit minus
> your total transportation costs.** Give an algorithm that solves this
> problem in time \$O(n^{2}2^{n})\$. (Hint: This is closely related to
> the traveling salesman problem.)

Here is my code:

(I assumed \$n < 16\$, to use `std::uint16_t` as a bitmask that represents the set of visited garages. I could suppose \$n < 32\$ and use `std::uint32_t` instead, but \$n = 31\$ is not feasible for \$O(n^{2}2^{n})\$)

```
std::pair<std::vector<std::size_t>, double> getMaxValue(const std::vector<double>& vals,
                                             const std::vector<std::vector<double>>& dist_costs) {
    std::tuple<std::uint16_t, std::size_t, double> ans {0, -1, std::numeric_limits<double>::lowest()};
    const std::size_t n = vals.size();
    assert(n < 16);

    // valueMap[i][j] is total max benefit up to path of length i that ends with garage j
    std::unordered_map<std::uint16_t, std::vector<double>> valueMap;
    valueMap[0].resize(n);
    for (std::size_t j = 0; j < n; ++j) {
        valueMap[0][j] = vals[j] - dist_costs[0][j + 1];
    }

    // subsets[i] is set of paths of length i:
    // each element in subsets[i] is uint16_t bitmask
    // where each bit represents whether a garage is visited or not.
    std::vector<std::unordered_set<std::uint16_t>> subsets (n + 1);

    // warning : n = 16 will cause (defined) infinite loop!
    for (std::uint16_t index = 0; index <= static_cast<std::uint16_t>((1u << n) - 1); ++index) {
        int cnt = std::popcount(index);
        subsets[cnt].insert(index);
    }

    // optimal back element to extend to unvisited j
    std::unordered_map<std::uint16_t, std::vector<std::size_t>> optimalBack;

    for (std::size_t k = 1; k < n; ++k) {
        for (auto subset_k : subsets[k]) {
            optimalBack[subset_k].resize(n);
            valueMap[subset_k].resize(n);
            for (std::size_t j = 0; j < n; ++j) {
                if (!(subset_k & (1u << j))) { // extend to unvisited j.
                    std::size_t max_i = -1;
                    double valueMap_subsetk_j = std::numeric_limits<double>::lowest();
                    for (std::size_t i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
                        if (subset_k & (1u << i)) { // backtrack the last visited.
                            auto subset_k_minus_i = subset_k & ~(1u << i);
                            double value_from_i_to_j = valueMap[subset_k_minus_i][i] + vals[j] - dist_costs[i + 1][j + 1];
                            if (valueMap_subsetk_j < value_from_i_to_j) {
                                valueMap_subsetk_j = value_from_i_to_j;
                                max_i = i;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    valueMap[subset_k][j] = valueMap_subsetk_j;
                    assert(max_i != -1);
                    optimalBack[subset_k][j] = max_i;
                    auto ans_candidate = valueMap_subsetk_j - dist_costs[j + 1][0];
                    // update best answer
                    if (std::get<2>(ans) < ans_candidate) {
                        ans = {subset_k | (1u << j), j, ans_candidate};
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    auto [optimalSet, optimalLast, optimalVal] = ans;
    // backtrack to construct optimal path.
    std::vector<std::size_t> optimalSequence;
    while (true) {
        optimalSequence.push_back(optimalLast);
        optimalSet = optimalSet & ~(1u << optimalLast);
        if (!optimalSet) {
            break;
        }
        auto optimalSecondLast = optimalBack[optimalSet][optimalLast];
        optimalLast = optimalSecondLast;
    }
    std::ranges::reverse(optimalSequence);
    return {optimalSequence, optimalVal};
}
```

Feel free to comment anything!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Use `std::bitset`

> I assumed \$n<16\$, to use `std::uint16_t` as a bitmask that represents the set of visited garages. I could suppose \$n<32\$ and use `std::uint32_t` instead, but `n=31` is not feasible for \$O(n^2 2^n)\$

There are a few flaws in this assumption. Even if `n=31` were not feasible, consider that `n=17` might be very feasible, so you would still need a `std::uint32_t`. Second, even `n=31` is not as unfeasible as you might think with today's hardware. Contemporary CPUs and GPUs can process multiple TFLOP/s. For example, an NVIDIA GeForce RTX 3090 can process 35.6 TFLOP/s, or \$2^{35}\$ FLOP/s. While expensive, this is just a single consumer graphics card. So if you only needed one FLOP per step of the algorithm, it would take only \$\frac{31^2 2^{31}}{2^{35}} = \frac{961}{16} \approx 60\$ seconds. Of course it will take a bit more than that, but it definitely isn't outside the realm of possibilities, even for a single PC.

I recommend you use a [`std::bitset`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/bitset) instead of an unsigned int for storing the bitmask. It is then easy to change the size of the bitset. Also, the way it is used, I don't think there is any benefit to making it only 16 bits. Only when you store many of them consecutively in memory would it help to choose the smallest possible size.

It will also help you distinguish more easily between a bitmask and a path length in your code.

## Naming things

`getMaxValue()` is not a great name. It doesn't explain what exactly this function is doing. It's even returning more than just a single value, so just by looking at the return type you know the name is a lie. If this function would be part of a larger program, consider naming it `calculateOptimalGarageSalePath()`.

The variable names inside the function are not super great. I see both camelCase and snake_case names, I recommend picking one style and sticking with it. They are mostly fine, except for `ans`. Is this an abbreviation of `answer`? But if so, it's actually not the final answer. But most importantly, use a `struct` instead of a `std::tuple`, so you can give names to each of the elements:

```
struct {
    std::bitset<16> subset;
    std::size_t lastGarage;
    double value;
} currentBest;

...

auto candidateValue = valueMap_subsetk_j - dist_costs[j + 1][0];
if (currentBest.value < candidateValue) {
    currentBest = {subset_k | (1u << j), j, candidateValue};
}
```

I would also pay attention to the function parameters and return value. It would be great if these things were more clearly named. To do that, I recommend creating two `struct`s; one describing a garage sale, and one describing the return type:

```
struct garage {
    double value;
    std::vector<double> dist_costs;
};

struct optimalPath {
    std::vector<std::size_t> garages;
    double value;
};

optimalPath calculateOptimalGarageSalePath(const std::vector<garage>& garages) {
    const std::size_t n = garages.size();
    ...
    return {optimalSequence, optimalVal};
}
```

Comment: "I recommend picking one style and sticking with it. " that would imply using so-called "snake case", as you are using standard library features and built-in types.

Comment: @JDługosz I did not intend to imply that. I think it is OK to use your own code style for your own functions, variables, types and so on. But if I had to recommend a style, I would indeed recommend snake_case :)